# Notepad++ auto indent

Tags: editor, notepad++, auto-indent

I have been using Notepad++ for quite sometime now. I didn't have any of the plugins installed, for all the time I used it. Some days ago, I moved on to another PC and I installed Notepad++ (v6.5.1) in it and for some reason the auto-indent does not seem to be working!! I remember it as working in my old PC without any exclusive setting.

I made sure that the auto-indent option under the MISC tab of Preferences is set. I know that I can use plugins like nppautoindent or indent by fold to achieve the desired result, but I would like to know why it isn't working and how I can set it right. Has anyone come across or heard of such an issue?

P.S. - I was coding in Ruby and I made sure that it was selected under the language menu. To make sure, I also tried Java. It didn't make any difference though!! I felt like I was using the featureless built in windows notepad!!

Comment: I think this might belong on http://superuser.com/, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: @TimS.how do i migrate this question to superuser?! should i re-ask there?